# Remove sections of XML file that not matches criteria - using bash

Tags: xml, bash, awk

I have large XML file looking something like this:

```
<A>
    <B id="XXX_City_Oslo">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="XXX_City_Bergen">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="XXX_City_Trondheim">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="XXX_City_Stavanger">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="1">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="2">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>

</A>
```

I wish to delete some of the  sections and its content that contain the string "City". The XML file will be to big do define all the sections that should be deleted. so easier to define what cities that should be kept. The only issue then are all of the section like "1" and "2" that I also want to keep These section does not contain the string "City".

Lets say I want to keep Oslo and Stavanger, using this command:

`awk '/<B.*>/ && !/id="XXX_City_Oslo"/  && !/id="XXX_City_Stavanger"/, /<\/B>/ {next} 1'`
This will then delete all the B sections, but leave Oslo and Stavanger. The issue here is that this will also delete the other B sections that does not contain the string "City".
Is it a simple method to only delete the cities that do not match the given input, and also not delete all the sections that doesn't contain the string "City" at all? eg. Something like this(please note the **/id="*City*"/**):

`awk '/<B.*>/ && **/id="*City*"/** && !/id="XXX_City_Oslo"/  && !/id="XXX_City_Stavanger"/, /<\/B>/ {next} 1'`

Please note that this is being ran on a linux environment without much options for adding other scripting languages/libraries and I want to follow the same approach using the awk to solve this.

Thanks in advance for any contribution!

Comment: Despite your note about the impossibility to install new libraries, I'd still recommend to process XML by an XML-aware tool. E.g. in XML, you'd just write `rm /A/B[contains(@id,"City") and not(xsh:match(@id, "Bergen|Stavanger"))]`.

Comment: Awk is the wrong tool for the job. This site is deluged with queries about how to handle bad XML, and this bad XML is all created by people who chose to use the wrong tools to do their XML processing.

Comment: @MichaelKay that's fine in theory but there are no mandatory POSIX tools to parse XML and often the XML to be parsed is a very specific, restricted subset of XML, often generated by some other tool in a very specific layout, and so there are cases where awk is perfectly adequate and/or the only tool available for the job. GNU awk has an XML library users can install by the way so you can't even just say that "awk is the wrong tool for the job" as that sounds like no awk has an XML parser.

Comment: Does the linux system have xsltproc?

Comment: @EdMorton I disagree with you very strongly indeed, but this isn't the place for the discussion.

Comment: @MichaelKay I agree this isn't the place for a discussion but I'm curious which statement(s) I made you disagree with: a) there are no mandatory POSIX tools to parse XML, or b) often the XML to be parsed is a very specific, restricted subset of XML, often tool-generated or c) in such cases awk is perfectly adequate and/or the only tool available for the job, or d) GNU awk has an XML library users can install. I'm also curious to know what **you** would do if you were on a POSIX system where you can't install non-mandatory tools and you have to process files containing a restricted set of XML

Comment: (a) the fact that the right tool isn't in your preferred toolbox is no excuse for using the wrong tool. (b) by writing code that only accepts a subset of XML you impose an unreasonable dependency on the creators of that XML: for example if they upgrade some software they use to generate the XML, they may unintentionally depart from that subset; (c) awk is not adequate, because any attempt to process XML using regular expressions is open to security problems e.g. through exploitation of comments and CDATA sections.

Comment: To amplify this, we see vast numbers of questions on SO saying "I need to generate XML conforming to restrictions imposed by the consumer of that XML because they aren't using a real XML parser to process it".

Comment: You seem to be deliberately avoiding addressing the main point that for some of us we don't get to use our **preferred** toolbox, we have to use a **required** toolbox which is the set of mandatory POSIX tools either because that's all that exists on the box we're developing on and we aren't allowed to install any other tools on it or we have to write code that will be portable to all POSIX systems. The idea that everyone has access to XML parsers is a nice theory but it's just that, and invariably in such situations the XML to be read is a tiny well-defined subset in a specific layout.

Comment: To amplify this, we see vast numbers of questions on SO saying "I need to parse a small, well-defined subset of XML using only mandatory POSIX tools as that's all I have on my system and I can't install any other tools" and the stock answer of "you have to use an XML parser" simply isn't useful. The fact that the input is XML in such cases is irrelevant - if the people producing the file and consuming it decided to invent "bobs interchange format" and use that instead of a subset of XML, it'd be exactly the same question with exactly the same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `AWK`, the `/../` is a regexp pattern matching expression.

Thus you simply have to add a `City` filter on top of the others :

```sh
awk '/<B.*>/ && !/id="XXX_City_Oslo"/  && !/id="XXX_City_Stavanger"/ && /City/, /<\/B>/ {next} 1'
```

**EDIT:** As @EdMorton usefully suggest in comment, you can reduce it to :

```sh
awk '/<B.*City.*>/ && !/id="XXX_City_(Oslo|Stavanger)"/ , /<\/B>/ { next } 1'
```

And if you intend to use that in production script, as @EdMorton states it, you should avoid hard-coding your tag identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(tgts,tmp,/,/)
    for (i in tmp) {
        goodCities["XXX_City_"tmp[i]]
    }
    FS = "\""
    inGoodBlock = 1
}
/^[[:space:]]*<B[[:space:]]*id="/ {
    inGoodBlock = ( ($2 ~ /_City_/) && !($2 in goodCities) ? 0 : 1 )
}
inGoodBlock
/^[[:space:]]*<\/B>/ {
    inGoodBlock = 1
}
```

```
$ awk -v tgts='Oslo,Stavanger' -f tst.awk file
<A>
    <B id="XXX_City_Oslo">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="XXX_City_Stavanger">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="1">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="2">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>

</A>
```

```
$ awk -v tgts='Trondheim' -f tst.awk file
<A>
    <B id="XXX_City_Trondheim">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="1">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>
    <B id="2">
        <C>
        ....
        </C>
    </B>

</A>
```